# solving the error 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse'

Tags: json, angular, express, routes

I deployed my angular 6 app to Heroku ( https://angulardictionary.herokuapp.com/).

But I'm getting the error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse.

I understand what this error means: The response returns html instead of JSON.
My question is: how can I fix it?

I tried:

res.send(object)

res.json(object)

Here's my code:

server.js

```
app.get('*', function(req,res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname +'/dist/frontend/index.html'));
});

app.get('/api/words', function(req, res){
 fs.readFile('newWords.xml', 'utf-8', function (err, data){
  if(err){
    console.log('error');
    //res.send(err);
  } else{
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
    let words = result['entry']['form'];
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(words));
```

web.service.ts:

```
getWords(name: string, option: any):Observable<Word[]>{

return this.http.get<Word[]>('/api/words',{
  params: {
    name:name,
    option:option
  }
}
);
```

}

and I call this function in: home.component.ts:

```
getWordList(){
    this.webservice.getWords(this.spelling, this.selected)
        .subscribe((res: Array<Word>)=> {
        this.elements = res.filter(d=> d.orth == this.spelling || d.asuddimIsem
        == this.spelling);


    }
}
```

It seems as if all the http calls go directly to the default route (app.get('*', function(req,res)), skipping (app.get('/api/words')).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as if all the http calls go directly to the default route `(app.get('*', function(req,res))`, skipping `(app.get('/api/words'))` this is correct. The order in which routes are defined matters. You have to put the wildcard `*` route at last. As for the other API, you may not need to stringify `JSON.stringify()` the response, you can simply do `res.send(words)`.